# Is it possible to dynamically use a route part to call passport strategy?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-router

Currently, I have the following code for many more oath provider:

```
// facebook
router.get("/facebook", passport.authenticate("facebook", { scope: ["email"] }));
router.get("/facebook/callback", passport.authenticate("facebook"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(chalk.blue("went into facebook callback"));
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/profile");
});

// github
router.get("/github", passport.authenticate("github"));
router.get("/github/callback", passport.authenticate("github"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(chalk.blue("went into github callback"));
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/profile");
});
```

Is there a way to unify that into an abstracted route? I.e. something like

```
// github
router.get("/:provider", passport.authenticate(:provider));
router.get("/:provider/callback", passport.authenticate(:provider), (req, res) => {
    console.log(chalk.blue("went into {:provider} callback"));
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/profile");
});
```

**Update:**
The following piece of code does what I want. Thx to @Usman Abdur Rehman.

```
function callbackDistributer(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params);
    global.provider = req.params.provider;
    next();
}

router.get(
    "/:provider/callback",
    callbackDistributer,
    (req, res, next) => {
        passport.authenticate(global.provider)(req, res, next);
    },
    (req, res) => {
        console.log(chalk.red("went into: " + global.provider));
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/profile");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a middleware function going before the passport.authenticate middleware

```
function ownMiddleware(req,res,next){
    global.provider = req.params.provider
    next()
}
```

and then use it in the route handler as

```
router.get("/:provider/callback", ownMiddleware ,passport.authenticate(global.provider), (req, res) => {
    console.log(chalk.blue("went into {:provider} callback"));
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/profile");
});
```

I think it should work

Comment: Nope this does not work. doesn't even go into the respective strategy.